# Makefile How to wrap lines in log files

Tags: logging, makefile

Currently using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, VS Code, with `SHELL=/bin/zsh`.

I have my makefile setup to log error outputs to a `err.log` file using the command `./myprogram 2> err.log` whenever I run the command `make test`. However, I want to wrap the lines such that every time a line exceeds a specified character limit per line (e.g. 80 characters), it wraps and continues on the next line (to improve readability).

How can I achieve this?

Additionally, VS Code supplies color coding for log files which helps in reading. However, when I tried to wrap the lines myself, the color disappears.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to wrap the lines of the standard output, you could use [fold](https://linux.die.net/man/1/fold):

```
./myprogram | fold -w 80
```

or

```
./myprogram | fold
```

(The default line length is 80.)

But a pipeline like this operates only on standard output, and leaves standard error unchanged. We could redirect standard error to standard output:

```
./myprogram 2>&1 | fold > err.log
```

but this would combine the standard output and standard error. To keep them separate, pipe the error through `fold`, send the wrapped error to the file and send the output to the screen, we must use a sequence of redirections using a third file descriptor (e.g. `3`):

```
{ ./myprogram 2>&1 1>&3 | fold -w 80 1>err.log; } 3>&1
```